# Locating Streitberg Rohmel paper

Tags: nonparametric

I'm looking for the paper:

*Streitberg and Rohmel (1986) **Exact calculations for permutation and rank tests: an introduction to some recently published algorithms.** Statist. Soft.Newsletter, 12, 10-17.*

Google Scholar shows a citation, but not a link, and says that it's cited by 60 other papers. It appears that the Statistical Software Newsletter was discontinued a few years back, or at least moved online to the csdassn.org, but I can't seem to find an archive section. My university library only has the newsletter from 1993 onward.

Does anyone have a suggestion of where I might find this paper, or better yet, actually have a copy?

Comment: Interlibrary loan?

Comment: Rather than asking for a pointer, this question would benefit from being rephrased as "What is a good summary of the key points in that paper?" (Otherwise, it is certainly *too localized* and will appear of limited interest for future users.)

Comment: Have you tried e-mailing original authors? Paper is quite old, but it is always a good idea to try.