# Excel Realstats MANN_EXACT function

Tags: excel, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm trying to compute some mann-whitney tests on my datas, and I use the really handy "Realstats".

As you can see on [this link](http://www.real-statistics.com/real-statistics-environment/supplemental-functions/), there are several functions available.

As a noob in stats, I used the MANN_EXACT function to gte my p-values, but after reading some articles I wonder if I shouldn't have used the MTEST function. I didn't find anything about the Mann-Whitney exact test on google.

What is the difference between these two ? When should I use each ?

Comment: What does the manual say about the difference between the two functions?

Comment: [This](http://www.real-statistics.com/non-parametric-tests/mann-whitney-test/mann-whitney-exact-test/) says "Based on the relationship between the Mann-Whitney Test and the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Test, we can modify the exact test described in Wilcoxon Rank-Sum Exact Test to provide an exact test for Mann-Whitney". But that makes no sense to me...

Comment: See [Why are there two forms for the Mann-Whitney U test statistic?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122985/17230) & [The exact distribution of Wilcoxon rank-sum statistic U](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13264/17230). (And I forgot to say "Edit your question rather than include additional info. in comments.")